# updating user create account code with stripe charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I built a rails app that creates an account as follows below.

Now I want it to charge a card using stripe before redirecting to the new account. 
The code for that is below.

How would i combine these two blocks into a single create action so the action in the controller accomplishes what is in both codes blocks, but in a single action?

I'm trying to add the second block to the first, not the other way around, since i have an entire login system built already.

Normal login

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Stripe create code

```
def create
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"],
                                                               card_token: 

    stripe_params["stripeToken"])
        raise "Please, check registration errors" unless @registration.valid?
        @registration.process_payment
        @registration.save
        redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
      rescue e
        flash[:error] = e.message
        render :new
      end
```